# Ruby - creating a grid

Tags: ruby, grid

This is very basic, but can someone explain in plain in english what exactly is happening in this code?

```
3.times do |row_index|
   board[row_index] = []
   3.times do |column_index|
      board[column_index] = []
      board[row_index][column_index] = nil
   end
end
end
```

Comment: The code is creating a 2-dimensional array, 3x3 to be exact, with entries set to `nil`. Note that `board[row_index] = []` initializes `board[row_index]` to an empty array so that `board[row_index][column_index] = nil` will make sense. However, `board[column_index] = []` should not be there (it's an error), and before the whole thing, you should have `board = []`. There's also an extra `end` which is in error.

Comment: How does the code know to make it a row versus a column. Is column_index and row_index a set thing? What does that mean exactly.

Comment: Why shouldn't board[column_index] = [] be there?

Comment: The first index of `board` is the row, not the column. That line `board[column_index] = []` serves no purpose and is, in fact, just wrong because the column number is being used as a row index. It would yield incorrect results if you weren't doing a square matrix (*e.g.* the number of columns was greater than the number of rows). In this case, rows are the first index, and columns are the second. A matrix is an array of arrays. The first index is the row number, and each row is an array. So the second index is the column number and points to the element in that row.

Comment: sorry, i think there is something i don't understand. how does it know that row_index is referring to making rows.  i can call it anything - i.e. row or bird, how does it know that i want it to make a row.

Comment: The programmer just decides that the first index is the row. :) It's somewhat of a convention to think of a 2D array/matrix in software as an array of rows, and each row an array of elements (columns). You could just as well index it and say, `board[column][row]` and it would work as long as the code was consistent about which is which. In your case, the code you show is not consistent.

Comment: so this : board[row_index][column_index]

Comment: this code board[row_index][column_index]  is nesting the column array in the row_index array?

Comment: In your case, yes. That's what the code has. And `board[column_index]` violates that convention. The rest of the code is fine, other than there's a failure to initialize `board = []` before the first loop.

Comment: and how would I code it to make the lines of the matrix print out

Comment: You really should read the Ruby documentation on [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html). An `Array` is enumerable and you can do, for example, `board.each { |row| ... }`. If that documentation doesn't help, do a Google search on "Ruby Array examples". Use `puts`, for example, to print. Ruby also has string formatting methods. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I will first correct your code and then will show you how to improve it with increasing simplifications.

Presumably the array `board` is initialized before your code and, because of the extra `end` is probably in a method, we need:

```
def initialize_board(n, val)
  board = Array.new(n)
  n.times do |row_index|
    board[row_index] = Array.new(n)
    n.times do |column_index|
      board[row_index][column_index] = val
    end
  end
  board
end

initialize_board(3, nil)
  #=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

You see that, to make the method more robust, I've made the board's size (`n`) and initialization value (`val`) variables. The method must return `board`, so we need `board` as the next-to-last line. (Because it is the last line of the method that is executed, `return board` is not needed.)

Firstly, since you have `board[row_index] =...`, `board` must be created as an array with `n` elements. That's what `Array.new(n)` does. Similarly, since you have `board[row_index][column_index] =...`, `board[row_index]` (for each value of `row_index`) must be created as an array with `n` elements:

```
board[row_index] = Array.new(n)
```

This works, but it's not very Ruby-like. Better would be to write:

```
def initialize_board(n, val)
  board = []
  n.times do |row_index|
    row = []
    n.times { |column_index| row << val } # or row.push(val)
    board << row # or board.push(val)
  end
  board
end

initialize_board(3, nil)
  #=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

Notice that `board` is initialized to an empty array, is then filled with rows, then `board` is returned. Similarly, `row` is initialized to an empty array, filled with copies of `val` and then appended to `board`. We can tighten that up by using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
def initialize_board(n, val)
  n.times.with_object([]) do |row_index, board|
    board << n.times.with_object([]) { |column_index, row| row << val }
  end
end

initialize_board(3, nil)
  #=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

We can now use `Array.new` with a block to create each row with the  default value:

```
def initialize_board(n, val)
  n.times.with_object([]) do |row_index, board|
    board << Array.new(n) { val }
  end
end

initialize_board(3, nil)
  #=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

and then do it again:

```
def initialize_board(n, val)
  Array.new(n) { Array.new(n) { val } }
end

arr = initialize_board(3, nil)
  #=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

There's one last thing I'd like to mention. Suppose we set:

```
arr[1][1] = 'cat'
```

Then

```
arr #=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, "cat", nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

as expected.

If, however, we had written:

```
def initialize_board(n, val)
  Array.new(n, Array.new(n, val))
end
```

Then:

```
arr = initialize_board(3, nil)
  #=> [[nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]] 

arr[1][1] = 'cat'

arr #=> [[nil, "cat", nil], [nil, "cat", nil], [nil, "cat", nil]]
```

which clearly is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time.do you have to create an array row within the array board? and then populate the array row? I don't fully understand what's happening here -   n.times do |row_index|
    row = []
    n.times { |column_index| row << val } # or row.push(val)
    board << row # or board.push(val)
  end  do you have to create an array row, within the array board? and then you need a second argument which is column index?

Comment: You could instead write: `n.times do |row_index| board << []; n.times { |column_index| board[-1] << val }`, but, one way or another, you need to create an empty array to which `val` is appended `n` times. I think it reads better to use an array `row` that is reinitialized to start empty for each row and then is appended to `board` after it is filled with `val` `n` times. If this is not clear, tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way in Ruby

> Input n defined as size of n x n matrix
>
> Example
>
> if n = 3
>
> Matrix size is 3 x 3

## Code

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i

# Array('A'..'Z').sample is random value from A to Z
matrix = Array.new(n) { Array.new(n) { Array('A'..'Z').sample } }
```

## Output

> [["D", "A", "M", "V"], ["X", "Q", "A", "E"], ["P", "D", "L", "S"],
> ["V", "M", "P", "Z"]]